# Javascript event in Chrome vs. Safari

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have an HTML element which looks like this:

```
<select class="indiv_unit" name="indiv_unit" id="indiv_unit">
```

and I am trying to trap select events (when the user makes a choice) in a Javascript/Backbone.js view, like this:

```
events : {

    "click select.indiv_unit" : 'changeIndivUnit',
},
```

Safari and Firefox browsers are able to catch the select events, but Chrome does not. I suspect that the problem for Chrome is that I am not "really" catching a select choice, but instead am catching a click in the select box. I tried things like this:

```
"select select.indiv_unit"
```

but that doesn't work, and doesn't look right. Can someone point out the correct way to detect a select event that would work in all browsers?

Comment: Wouldn't catching the 'change' event suit your needs?

Comment: @Loamhoof, yes, I just need to know that it changed. What would that look like? "change select.indiv.unit" ?

Comment: Yeah I think that should work. I'm testing it right away (as I'm sure you're doing it anyway).

Comment: @Loamhoof, you've done it. I am very grateful. If you wish, please submit an "answer", and I will accept it right away. I am very grateful that you answered so fast. If you can, when you answer, please explain why "change" works and "click" doesn't. (I like to understand things) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
'change select.indiv_unit': 'changeIndivUnit'
```

You can test it with http://jsfiddle.net/T8Dsf/.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. Any explanation - why "click" didn't do it but "change" did - would be gratefully received. Thanks for your very speedy reply.

Comment: @sploiber I must admit I'd be glad to search for the reason if you could reproduce that behavior. If I try to replace `change` by `click` in the jsfiddle above, it seems to work just fine :o Well, at least your problem is fixed.

Comment: I am not sure why it wasn't working in Chrome. I suspect I have a lot to learn about different browser functionality. I mostly work in Safari, but Chrome and Firefox can do very different things. I'm leaving IE out for the moment. Thanks again!

Comment: As a last 'kinda strange' comment, both Chrome and Safari are Webkit based browsers, so it's really weird to work for one and not the other. Well, until Chrome begins using Blink.